# C, Different GCC, fflush() not working?

Tags: c, gcc, stdin, fflush

I'm a beginner programmer. I have a function that doesn't let float numbers or characters to be inputted. It was working fine with gcc 3.4.2, but now I updated to 4.7.1 and it isn't working properly. It only works now with the first input a[0]. If I input lets say 'x', it will show "Wrong input", however if I input for example '1' for a[0], and then 'x' for a[1], it will still say Input OK and assign '1' to a[1]; How can I fix this? Thank you!

```
void initArray(unsigned int a[]) {

double q;
int x, c;

for ( x = 0; x < SIZE; x++){
    printf("a[%d] ", x);
    printf("Enter number: ");

    scanf("%lf", &q);

    if (q == (unsigned int) q) {
        printf("Input OK.\n");
        a[x] = q;
        fflush(stdin);
    }
    else {
        printf("Wrong Input\n");
        fflush(stdin);
        x--;
    }
}
printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: have you tried debuging your code? or at least some kind of logging ?

Comment: _If the given stream is of the input type, then the behavior of the function is undefined._: from http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush

Comment: your a array is unsigned int and you are reading double from int wgy ?!. Why not reading directely unsigned int from the stdin "%u"

Comment: @user2211796 I updated my answer. my answer contains now the adequate code to read with the way you described in your question. I test it and it works

Comment: From the comp.lang.c FAQ, see: http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush.html and http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush2.html

Answer (score 3):

You should check the return value of `scanf`. It returns the number of items it managed to "scan", which will be zero if it failed to scan anything, for example when you input `'x'`:

```
if (scanf("%lf", &q) == 1)
{
    printf("Input OK.\n");
    a[x] = q;
}
else
{
    printf("Wrong Input\n");
    x--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to you to replace

```
scanf("%lf", &q);
```

with

```
while ((c=(scanf(" %lf%c", &q, &tmp) !=2 || !isspace(tmp)))
       || (q != (unsigned int) q)) {
    printf("Your input is invalid please enter again: ");
    if(c) scanf("%*[^\n]");
}
```

The `scanf("%*[^\n]");` clean your stdin so no need any more for `fflush(stdin)` in your code

So your code could be:

```
void initArray(unsigned int a[]) {

double q;
int x, c=0;
char tmp;


for ( x = 0; x < SIZE; x++){
    printf("a[%d] ", x);
    printf("Enter number: ");

    while ( (c=(scanf(" %lf%c", &q, &tmp) !=2 || !isspace(tmp)))
               || (q != (unsigned int) q)) {
       printf("Your input is invalid please enter again: ");
       if(c) scanf("%*[^\n]");
    }

    a[x] = q;
}
printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: @Armin it will be catched with next scan of `scanf(" %lf", &q)` that why I added a space at the beginning of the string format of this scanf. So your downvote is wrong

Comment: No you leave it in stdin, when exiting for loop. Go debug your own code.

Comment: It is really a shame you don't see why it stays in.

Comment: @Armin I did not say you are wrong. but in real world have you ever seen some one adding a `fgetc()` for example after a `scanf("%d")` to catch the `'\n'` remaining in the stdin. the response is no, only if we want to read more data from stdin and in this case it's recommended to add space at the beginning of the string format of the new `scanf()`like I did in my case `" %lf"`. And If I have finished the read from buffer (in my case go out from `for` loop) and there is `'\n'` remaining why I should add a supplement instruction to get the remaining '\n' and I m not going to read any more ?

Comment: @Armin Hope you have understand my point of view (it useless to get the newline remaining in the stdin because I m not going to read any more) . And I hope do not take it serious. I m kidding with "loool"

Comment: @Armine I updated my answer. the old answer contains some limitations. the new answer contains now the adequate code to read with the way described by the OP in his question. I test it and it works for all the cases. BTW this solution catch the remaining newline after quit the for loop. Hope you are happy ;-)